# Query doesnt work on android, column '_id' does not exist?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I hope anyone can help me with this.

I'm using sqlite3 on my android app. I'm trying to do this query:

```
mCursor = conexion.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT employee.name, company.name FROM employee "
                                               + " INNER JOIN company "
                                               + " ON (employee.idCompany=company._id) ORDER BY employee.name", null);
```

This is my schema:

```
CREATE table company ("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "name TEXT NOT NULL);";

CREATE table employee ("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                     + "name TEXT NOT NULL, "
                     + "fullName TEXT NOT NULL, "
                     + "idCompany INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                     + "FOREIGN KEY(idCompany) REFERENCES company (_id));";
```

When I run this query on my android app I get the following error:

```
05-09 22:35:23.170: E/AndroidRuntime(10920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 22:35:23.170: E/AndroidRuntime(10920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ej.ej/com.ej.ej.controlador.AplicacionActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

If I run the same query but with select *:

```
mCursor = conexion.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employee "
                                               + " INNER JOIN company "
                                               + " ON (employee.idEmployee=company._id) ORDER BY employee.name", null);
```

No problem I get, it works fine. But since in my schema I have name for company and name for employee I need to differentiate both.

I tried doing this query using cmd and adb commands and it works. I really don't get why the error!!

EDITED: I made it work, as @HalR suggested in the query (dont know why) I have to retrieve the ids. So now I have:

```
mCursor = conexion.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT company._id, employee.name as employee, company.name as company FROM employee "
                                           + " INNER JOIN company "
                                           + " ON (employee.idCompany=company._id) ORDER BY employee.name", null);
```

But I had one more issue and it wasnt in the query, it was on my ActivityFragment (thanks to @Hoan Nguyen, he made me see this part of the code again):
Listing my employees, I was getting the name of my employee and the idCompany. Don't know why, but this was looking for the _id of Company instead of idCompany of Employee.

```
String[] from = new String[] { "name", "idCompany"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewNombreIzq,  R.id.textViewNombreCent };

ListView lvEmployee = (ListView) view.findViewById (android.R.id.list);

ListClientsCursorAdapter notes = new ListClientsCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_file_client, mCursorEmployee, from, to, 0);
lvEmployee .setAdapter(notes);
```

I just changed:

```
String[] from = new String[] { "name", "idCompany"};
```

For:

```
String[] from = new String[] { "employee", "company"};
```

And now is fine. Thanks to all, for your help I really apreciated :).

Comment: there is no idEmployee

Comment: no, there is idCompany. My employee references its Company.

Comment: Do you have a listview in your app?

Comment: I have a ListFragment. Do you want to see my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
mCursor = conexion.getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT employee.idCompany, employee.name, company.name FROM employee "
                                               + " INNER JOIN company "
                                               + " ON (employee.idCompany=company._id) ORDER BY employee.name", null);
```

Note:  You need to make sure you specify the column name you are comparing in the section just after the SELECT.

Comment: yes, that's right. But even trying that I get the same error. It's really weird!.

Comment: see my edit above-- you need to mention the employee.idCompany also in the SELECT or the statement won't know anything about it.

Comment: I still get the error. Already did that. It just make no sense

Comment: I made it work, and this was part of the solution. So thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

**first**, I in your `CREATE TABLE employee` statement you used the lable `full name` as a column label. If it is not a typo here, please change it to something like `full_name`. you can't just use spaces in column labels this way.

**second**, use this query string:
`SELECT employee.name, company.name FROM employee INNER JOIN company ON (employee.idCompany=company._id) ORDER BY employee.name`. Notice the `ON` expression. it's `employee.idCompany` not `employee.idEmployee`.

fix those first, and let me know if the error still exists.

Comment: yes sorry, those are typos because my query is in spanish and I traslated to english for better comprenhension. I have it right in my app. So, this is not my error. And remember that select * works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to name your column as `_id` in your table. for a example, you can create column as `company_id` in your `company` table and when you write your query, you can specify this column as below.

`select company_id as _id, name from company`.

Comment: So, should I definitely has to change my schema ids?. But, is there any issue for calling _id??

Comment: names makes no difference.